# Unity 5 disabling a script

Tags: c#, unity

I'm using Unity 5 and want to disable a script called Unit based on whether the instance is a client or a server. I have tried using:

```
GetComponent("Unit").enabled = false;
```

However I get hit with this error:

> `Assets/Scripts/DisablingUnitScriptIfPlayer.cs(14,46): error CS1061: Type UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for 'enabled' and no extension method 'enabled' of type 'UnityEngine.Component' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Looking at some tutorials, this worked in previous versions, but I can't find how to make this work for Unity 5. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check solution described [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/923325/disabling-unknown-script-components-in-unity-5.html)

For your case it would be :

```
(GetComponent("Unit") as MonoBehaviour).enabled = false;
```

Warning this will crash if the "Unit" component is not deriving from MonoBehavior (if this is a script you wrote, it should ...)

## EDIT:

The solution proposed by Lohoris in comments is much cleaner and faster, and actuall the official way to do it fom the [doc](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html):

*It is better to use GetComponent with a Type instead of a string for performance reasons. Sometimes you might not be able to get to the type however, for example when trying to access a C# script from Javascript. In that case you can simply access the component by name instead of type.*

So the good code is :

```
GetComponent<Unit>().enabled = false;
```

Which will still of course crash if your object has no Unit component.

Comment: This is ok but this syntax is really bad… you should be using `GetComponent<Unlit>().enabled` instead. Never use strings if you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a safe version of @VB_overflow's answer, you could do this:

```
MonoBehaviour unit = (GetComponent("Unit") as MonoBehaviour);
if (unit != null)
{
     unit.enabled = false;
}
else
{
     Debug.Log("<color=red>Error:</color> Unit behavior not found, can't disable");
}
```

Here's another version using strong typing based on a comment from @Lohoris, this is more recommended as it is not as fragile to changing of said class:

```
MonoBehaviour unit = GetComponent<UnitBehaviorClass>();
if (unit != null)
{
     unit.enabled = false;
}
else
{
     Debug.Log("<color=red>Error:</color> Unit behavior not found, can't disable");
}
```

That way, if it **does** blow up because of a code change down the road, you'll know why and where to look. Practicing safe handling of possible null references is a good practice to get in the habit of!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a public class of type your script name and then just use this variable and `.enabled = false`.

Comment: Went with the above, thanks for your reply though :)